# Recommend/Suggestion on this table design....

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema

I have three table here....
One is menu, and second is drink, and food.

One menu data can only have either one drink or one food.

So, the menu table have something like this....
[id][type][type_fk]

if the menu table type is "D", it will find the drink table, and use the type_fk, to find the drink... ...Here is a more detail example:

```
id:1,type:D, type_fk:1
id:2,type:F, type_fk:1
```

in the drink table, we have

```
id:1, name:coke, unit:ml
```

in the food table, we have

```
id:1, name:chicken
```

The result why I want to separate two tables is because the drink table have "unit" column, but the food table don't have this... ...So, I will achieve information from user based on the type and the type_fk. So, in the first example, I can get the "coke", and the second one, I can get the "chicken".

Please drop your comments on this design.

Comment: What are you trying to achive is called exclusive relationship and it's common scenario. Usually it's realized by having proper trigger allowing to have only one of two foreign keys set. If you would keep it your way (only one fk field) you may loose you database integrity, by allowing to delete elements from drinks or food table. No auto integrity checks that way.

Comment: do u mean that I will spend many effort on db maintenance?

Comment: rather on writing lot of integrity check triggers that are normally hidden behind the scenes of foreign key relationship and keep all that stuff together. and thats only the top of the iceberg, if you are planning use of replication or other out of the box technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you have a single table instead of 2 tables:

```
Menu (Id, ItemId)
Item (Id, Name, Type, Unit)
```

The reason behind that is to enforce referential integrity. Menu.ItemId will be a foreign key that references Item.Id. If you have 2 tables you won't be able to enforce referential integrity.

I believe you shouldn't worry about sparse columns. For example store the Unit of chicken as piece or leave it empty.

Edit:
If you want to avoid having a sparse table, a table with some columns not being used, then you might consider something like:

```
Menu (Id, ItemId)
Item (Id, Name)
ItemProperties (ItemId, Name, Value)
```

For example

```
Item:
-----
Id    Name
1     Chicken
2     Coke

ItemProperties:
---------------
ItemId    Name    Value
1         Price   10
1         Type    Chinese
2         Price   1
2         Unit    ml
2         Size    300
```

This way you are keeping referential integrity and avoiding sparse tables.

If you are using SQL Server 2008, check this [SQL Server 2008 Sparse Columns](http://blogs.technet.com/b/andrew/archive/2008/02/28/sql-server-2008-sparse-columns.aspx)

Comment: I see your point, but the Food may have other attribute that the drink don't have, it only a simple example. If I combine two table into one, I am worry about there is more and more attribute I need to put in...

Comment: It is a trade off between integrity and having a sparse column. In SQL Server 2008 there is a feature called sparse columns to avoid such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no problem here. This design will do.